# Adding Subdomain of Public Domain to Existing Internal Windows domain

Tags: windows, subdomain, internal-dns

I'm new to Windows Server and DNS servers. Current setup:

- Windows domain is `corp.example.com`
- `example.com` is our public domain of our internet website, hosted on a external VPS.
- A local website running on the Windows domain (on VM and Ubuntu server with Apache2 and `192.168.1.10` internal IP) is externally available via `support.example.com` on the internet. I have pointed that subdomain via WHM to external IP address of our company and forwarded the IP and port `80` via router to `192.168.1.10:80`. Is that a correct way to do so?

Now we want to access that website internally via `support.example.com` without uploading and downloading the traffic via internet. Adding `CNAME` or `A` record results in `support.corp.example.com`.
Is it possible to add `support.example.com` on internal DNS server so employees could access the local website locally via `support.example.com`?

Comment: example.com is hosted on a VPS on an internet hosting company.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! It's better to add more details by editing the question instead of commenting it. I've formatted your first post as a reference for you on how to make informative and readable posts, that will more likely to get quality answers.

Comment: Thanks for the re-formatting and sure, I'll use this formatting in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have to congratulate you for doing things right! A subdomain of an existing company domain is the recommended AD domain, as using the same domain for AD will cause problems. This is a good starting point, and you have configured your DNS, AD and port forward pretty well.

In DNS Manager, it's possible to add a new primary *Forward Lookup Zone* for the subdomain `support.example.com` instead of `example.com`. That will go to the same place where you already have `corp.example.com`, but alongside it instead of under it. This way, both the subdomains are handled internally, but `example.com` *recursively* (i.e. eventually using the *authoritative* servers).

You can now point `@ A` i.e. `(same as parent folder)` of `support.example.com` to `192.168.1.10`.